# Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property or initializer

Tags: swift, swift3, selector

Can anyone tell me why this code gives the error message "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property or initializer"?

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:#selector(updateTimer(until: 3)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Here's the function:

```
func updateTimer(until endTime: Int) { 
    counter -= 1
    timeLabel.text = String(counter)
    if counter == endTime {
        step += 1
    }
}
```

What I have tried:
1. Adding @objc in front of the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The selector of a target / action method must be declared either without parameter or with one parameter passing the affected object.

In case of a `Timer` use the `userInfo` parameter to pass data.

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector:#selector(updateTimer(_:)), userInfo: 3, repeats: true)   


func updateTimer(_ timer: Timer) { 
    let endTime = timer.userInfo as! Int
    counter -= 1
    timeLabel.text = String(counter)
    if counter == endTime {
        step += 1
    }
}
```

If the enclosing class does not inherit form `NSObject` you have to add the `@objc` attribute to the action method.

Comment: For timers the parameter is required. *The selector should have the following signature: timerFireMethod: (including a colon to indicate that the method takes an argument).* Side note - Also, in Swift 4 the `@objc` or `@obcMembers` on the class is probably required.

Comment: @Sulthan That's not true. `updateTimer()` without parameter works, too. *should have* is not *must have* ;-)