# Calling a function through #selector with parameters

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I'm wanting to call a function and give it parameters using the `#selector`. However, I get the error:

> "Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer"

```
@objc func changeCrypto(crypto: String) {
    //stuff
}

func constructMenu() {
    let menu = NSMenu()

    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Bitcoin", action: #selector(changeCrypto(crypto: "bitcoin")), keyEquivalent: "B"))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Ethereum", action: #selector(changeCrypto(crypto: "ethereum")), keyEquivalent: "E"))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Litecoin", action: #selector(changeCrypto(crypto: "litecoin")), keyEquivalent: "L"))
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
    menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit It", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))

    statusItem.menu = menu
}
```

Comment: I don't know swift, but I'd guess that it's because you are actually executing `changeCrypto`, so you are passing the *return value* of `changeCrypto` rather than `changeCrypto` itself

Comment: Post the complete and exact error message in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy That is the complete error message

Comment: @JDB No, that's not the issue at all.

Comment: You should review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Argument+of+%27%23selector%27+does+not+refer+to+an+%27%40objc%27+method%2C+property%2C+or+initializer) from the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property or initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493778/argument-of-selector-does-not-refer-to-an-objc-method-property-or-initial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! I changed it to the following..

```
@objc func changeCrypto(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
//Here I call the title of the Menu Item pressed
print(sender.title)
}

func constructMenu() {
let menu = NSMenu()

menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Bitcoin", action: #selector(changeCrypto(_:)), keyEquivalent: "B"))
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Ethereum", action: #selector(changeCrypto(_:)), keyEquivalent: "E"))
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Litecoin", action: #selector(changeCrypto(_:)), keyEquivalent: "L"))
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem.separator())
menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit It", action: #selector(NSApplication.terminate(_:)), keyEquivalent: "q"))

statusItem.menu = menu
}
```

Comment: Also, you can use the `NSMenuItem.identifier` instance variable as a container for the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MenuItemForCrypto: NSMenuItem {
    enum coin {
        case bitcoin, ethereum, litecoint, nameItCoin
    }
    var name:coin?
}

...

let b = NSMenuItem(title: "Bitcoin", action: #selector(changeCrypto), keyEquivalent: "B")
b.name = .bitcoin
menu.addItem(b)
...

@objc func changeCrypto(_ sender: MenuItemForCrypto) {
    if sender.name == .bitcoin {
        print("It is Bitcoin. Go buy it!")
    }
}
```